# How to install node js

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have been trying to install node.js on my Windows 8.1 so I can start using react native, but I keep getting an error when trying to install node.js. It keeps saying something about it is not compatible with my version of Windows. Is there another way to install it or I need to upgrade my system version?

Comment: I would try https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows I may try that tonight on Windows 10.

Comment: You should really upgrade to a more recent version of Windows. Mainstream support for 8.1 ended on 01/09/2018, over three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64-bit system use this [link](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-x64.msi) to download the latest compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed node.js without issue on Windows 10. Try upgrading to Windows 10 and see if that solves your problem. Mainstream support ended on January 9, 2018 for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

check your system type 64-bit or 32-bit, download the suitable node js version. you can find the steps to installing
https://infinityraj.blogspot.com/2021/11/how-to-download-and-install-nodejs.html

Answer (score 0):

To install #nodejs on Windows.

Step 1- Download Node js .exe file from node js official website https://nodejs.org/

Setep 2 - Click on it & allow permission from clicking next button.

You see your node successfully installed. To check version use `node -v`.

For more details you can check reference from [How To Install Node js in your computer](https://youtu.be/79p7SZuENeE)